# Running an exe from Java gives different result unlike running from command prompt

Tags: java, cmd

I have an executable that generates some file, and I need to call this executable from a Java application. The command goes like this

```
Generator.exe -outputfile="path/to/file" [some other params]
```

It works fine on the command prompt, but running it from Java,all steps are executed (which means the executable was called properly), but the file is not created, here is my code:

```
try {
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"path/to/Generator.exe", "-outputfile=path/to/file", param1, param2,..etc});
}
catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I got no errors in the exe log,and I have no way to debug it, but this seems as a problem with my java application, I see that I am trying the same exact command.. what am I missing?

Comment: Environment variables?

Comment: *but this seems as a problem with my java application* Your java application that only calls the other program and does nothing else itself? Yeah. That must be like, totally, broken.

Comment: It could be a working directory problem: Is the java program started from the same directory as where your exe is run? Try specifying an absolute path (one that starts with a slash) for the output file.

Comment: There are programs that do not run correctly unless you empty their stdout. You should find an example that runs an executable with environment, working directory and clears stdout and stderr

Answer (score 0):

I have a second approach for you. Try with the below. Here you are creating a `output.txt` file to see the output from the `exe` file. If successful you can comment out that line. Hope this will help you.

```
String[] command ={"path/to/Generator.exe", "-outputfile=path/to/file", "param1"};
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
pb.redirectOutput(new File("C:\\log\\output.txt"));
try {
    Process p = pb.start();
    p.waitFor();       

} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch (Exception e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I have tried that approach but unfortunately it also did not work

Comment: Your main problem is with `={"path/to/Generator.exe", "-outputfile=path/to/file", "param1"};` try to execute any exe with out any parameter or with a single parameter only.